# Listing geodatabases in local SQL Express Workgroup ArcSDE using ArcPy/Python?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, list

I would like to create a list of the multiple geodatabases that sit in my local SQL Express Workgroup SDE server.

I have set up a connection using the "Database Connections\Connection to MyComputer_SQLEXPRESS.sde", but there doesn't seem to be any arcpy functions that expose the geodatabases.

It seems to identify the connection to a workspace, but doesn't give any information for what is in the workspace.

I know I can connect to each geodatabase separately and retrieve information about each of them, but I really need to get just a list of the geodatabases themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arcpy.da walk function.

Check the help doc for an example of how to print all FeatureClasses in a workspace.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000023000000